# ANDROID: JSONArray save in Internal Storage to work without internet conection

Tags: android, internal-storage

I have a PHP JSON that sends me JSONArray.

```
  public JSONArray lastTweet()throws ClientProtocolException,IOException,JSONException{
      StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);
      HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
      HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);
      int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
      if(status == 200){
          HttpEntity e = r.getEntity();
          String data = EntityUtils.toString(e);
          JSONArray timeline = new JSONArray(data);
         return timeline;
      }
    return null;

  }
```

I can get Object and values from this JSONArray (timeline), but it work only then application have internet conection. I want to save this JSON in my internal storage like a json file and after work with this file in offline mod. How i can do this?

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences, Files or Sqlite databases, depending of your project.

Comment: you can look for a http cache library ... or save String `data` to the file/shared pref and next time if there is no internet connection (or any error occured) use this stored value ... now, solution for all pieces of this problem can be easily found in the internet

Comment: Can you help me with the some cod for save String data to the file please? Or some link with example. I trying to save in file but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [JSON Simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) library which allows easy encoding/decoding of JSON files.

Examples: [Encoding](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples)

Then it's just plain:

```
try {
    outStream = openFileOutput("tweet.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outStream.write(json.getJSONString().getBytes());
    outStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However if you do not want to store it for forever, or for re-sending purposes, I recommend using **Cache**
Mind that cache can be automatically wiped, so it's up to you. More on this, as always, on the Android developers site: [Android: Saving Files # Write Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage)

**UPDATE:**
Turns out that android JSONObject.toString() produces coherent JSON output that can be saved to a file the way desciber above, without any 3rd party library, however you would need to marshall it back to JSONObject/Array/Primitive by yourself, and that will take some extra work.

Comment: Hello! thank you for answer! But where i need to put this part of cod in my CLASS? If i put this in asyncktask app give me ERROR the same in onCreate.